# Problem installing Acceleo on eclipse 64bit

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

I've just installed Eclipse Helios 64bit but when i try to install Acceleo, te download seems endless and Eclipse seems blocked.

Is there someone that can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the member of the dev' team of Acceleo and I am always working on a 64bits Eclipse with a 64 bits virtual machine and there are no problems. If you are experiencing this problem it is because of a timeout of the update site. Right now, it is the release of the sixth milestone of all the Eclipse projects so the server tends to be overloaded. You can try it again or just wait a few hours. If you absolutely want Acceleo today, you can always download the zip version directly from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/downloads/?project=acceleo).

Comment: Hi. a lot of hours later the problem persist. I have downloaded the zip version and copied the plug-in folder and the features folder into the eclipse folder. When I start eclipse now I'm able to create an Acceleo project, but when I try to run it I obtain this problem:   

An internal error occurred during: "Launching Generate".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

Answer (score 0):

The very first install of anything in a new Eclipse tend to be extremely long (Eclipse usually contacts all of its available update sites and checks for update on every single installed plugin before doing anything).

Within a new Eclipse and with a lot of update sites available, the longest I've seen it take for a single install was about 10 minutes. You can usually check whether Eclipse is actually doing something by opening the "Progress" view (Window > Show View > Progress).